# modifications in legend are not saved by using saveas

Tags: matlab, legend, matlab-figure

I just got some strange behaviour when saving a figure by using saveas. You should be able to reproduce this with this:

```
%just plot a line:
plot(1:10);
legend('line 1')
%find the line (not the best solution, but its working here):
temp=findall(legend,'type','line')
%modify the marker of the line within the legend:
set(temp(1),'Marker','o')
%save it:
saveas(gcf,'Test','fig')
```

if you now open the figure, the modifications within the legend seem to be gone.

The question is:

How can I save it the way it is displayed including the changes of the legend?

and perhaps, if someone knows:

what is the reason for this behaviour of saveas?

additional info: Matlab 2013a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are changing the legend but not the marker on the line.  When Matlab loads the saved figure, it automatically sets the legend to match the line/marker.  I doubt if you can change this behavior.